# Photo slightly moved and no working links on Safari

Tags: html, css

for past 2h I'm struggling with an phone image used as href to allow calling on mobile version. After doing it, my links don't want to work anymore.
Here is the code:

```css
.shoptext
{
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 150px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
}
.shoptext2
{
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
}
.shopicons
{
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: -125px;
    animation: fadein 2s;

}
.shopicons .shopicons2 > a > img
{
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
    margin-top: -105px;
}
.shopicons .shopicons2 > a
{
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 350px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: inherit;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!--Temporary-->
<div class="shoptext">
    <p>Już niedługo... &#128522;</p>
</div>

<div class="shoptext2">
    <p>Bądź na bieżąco!</p>
</div>
<div class=shopicons>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/bandirose.flowerbox" target="_blank" class="tilelink">
        <i class="icon-facebook"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/bandi_rose/" target="_blank" class="tilelink">
        <i class="icon-instagram"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="shopicons2">
        <a href="tel:555666777" target="_blank" class="tilelink">
        <img src="img/telefon.png" alt="nrtelefonu" />
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Temporary-->
```

And an image from Safari:
[image]

What's interesting, on Android, links are working just fine, but still a phone image is slightly moved despite a browser.

Comment: Have you made certain this is not a problem caused by the image? Also, give us the resources to make this a _reproducible_ problem so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

It was hard to reproduce your problem without **access to the images** you are using.
Still, by looking at your code for a while I can note some improvements that will probably solve your problem and help down the road.

#### Use lists

I recommend changing you `div` -list style to a proper `ul` list. This is possible with an attempt like this:

**HTML**

```
<div style="background-color: white; height:1000px;">
  <div class="shoptext">
    <p>Już niedługo... &#128522;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="shoptext2">
    <p>Bądź na bieżąco!</p>
  </div>
  
  <ul class="shopicons_list">
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/bandirose.flowerbox" target="_blank" class="tilelink">
        <i class="icon-facebook">test1</i>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/bandi_rose/" target="_blank" class="tilelink">
        <i class="icon-instagram">test2</i>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="tel:555666777" target="_blank" class="tilelink">
        <i><img src="img/telefon.png" alt="nrtelefonu" />test3</i>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.shoptext {
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 150px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  animation: fadein 2s;
}

.shoptext2 {
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 70px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  animation: fadein 2s;
}

.shopicons {
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 70px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: -125px;
  animation: fadein 2s;

}

.shopicons_list {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.shopicons_list li {
  float: left;
}

.shopicons_list > li > a {
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: okay, thank you. I'm just a beginner and still working on as clean code as possible

Comment: No problem. Another thing you can consider doing is using a `div` as a _container_ for your images. This is an easy solution that prevents them from using scaled size. In addition, I suspect your are using an icon font. I would recommend putting in the effort to get familiar with __icon sprite sheets__ if you want greater flexibility and overall more control.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier to control the size and positioning of the phone if we make it an integral part of the div rather than have it as an image in its own right - taking up space which has to be manipulated.

So, to get rid of the arithmetic with pxs etc and hope to head for a responsive implementation here's a snippet which has taken out the img completely, redefined the shopicons2 CSS to have the telephone as a background image. We make it have the same size as the icons by pretending there is an icon there and just making it transparent (you may have to decide just how wide you want your phone to be and choose an icon appropriately).

I don't have access to your icons so I've used ordinary characters. Just remove them and see what happens.

Here's the snippet:

```css
.shoptext
{
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 150px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
}
.shoptext2
{
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
}
.shopicons
{
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: -125px;
    animation: fadein 2s;

}

.shopicons .shopicons2
{   color: transparent;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXiOj.png);/* put in your own image */
    background-size: auto 80%;/* increase or decrease this depending on how it looks compared to the icons */
    background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<!--Temporary--> 
        <div class="shoptext">
            <p>Już niedługo... &#128522;</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="shoptext2">
            <p>Bądź na bieżąco!</p>
        </div>
        <div class=shopicons>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/bandirose.flowerbox" target="_blank" class="tilelink">
                <i class="icon-facebook">F</i>
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/bandi_rose/" target="_blank" class="tilelink">
                <i class="icon-instagram">I</i>
            </a>
        <!--    <div class="shopicons2">-->
                <a href="tel:555666777" target="_blank" class="tilelink shopicons2">
   <!--  <img src="img/telefon.png" alt="nrtelefonu" /> -->
              <i class="icon-instagram">T</i>
            </a>
         <!--   </div>-->
        </div>
        <!--Temporary-->
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into it